# I can't fit DataTable on page I get pixel error

Tags: flutter

Hello Everyone I have a DataTable consists of 5 columns.4. It does not appear after the colon. I want them all to fit on the page, I don't want to scroll left and right. Here is the view

[image]

The Error I Get
`════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════ A RenderFlex overflowed by 7.0 pixels on the right.`
My datatble codes :

```
 Widget dataWidgetList() {
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height * 0.2,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: filterList.isNotEmpty ? filterList.length : 0,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return DataTable(
            // datatable widget
            columns: const [
              // column to set the name
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Palet No'),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Hücre'),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Miktar'),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Toplam'),
              ),
              DataColumn(
                label: Text('Kalan'),
              ),
           
            ],

            rows: const [
              // row to set the values
              DataRow(cells: [
                DataCell(Text('ValCol1')),
                DataCell(Text('ValCol2')),
                DataCell(Text('ValCol3')),
                DataCell(Text('ValCol4')),
                DataCell(Text('ValCol5')),
              ]),
            ],
          );
         
        },
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SfDataGrid with width property.

return SfDataGrid(
source: _employeeDataSource,
columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
columns: [
GridColumn(columnName: 'id', label: Text('ID'), width: 50),
GridColumn(columnName: 'name', label: Text('Name'), width: 50),
GridColumn(columnName: 'designation', label: Text('Designation'), width: 50),
GridColumn(columnName: 'salary', label: Text('Salary'), width: 50),
);

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, Stackoverflow seems to be very busy, not letting me edit the answer)